# New to Python - Django manage.py runserver invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm setting up a new environment for a new project and I'm getting an SyntaxError: invalid syntax when running python manage.py runserver

Greater details

```
File "manage.py", line 16
) from exc
     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'personal_portfolio.settings')
try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: I didn't create it - it was auto generated. Sorry, first time even setting this up. Following this: https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/

Comment: Code was created for Python 3.0 or later but run with a 2.x Python.

Answer (score 1):

It's like @Michael Butscher said, you're running it with python 2.0 and that is what is giving the problem.

Try running it like `python3 manage.py`. When you have both python 2 and python 3 installed in your system, running `python` runs python2.

Hope that helps.